# Right notation for convex hull?

Tags: geometry, terminology

I have $n$ triangles like in the figure below
[image]

And I want to refer mathematically to the polygon created by the upper lines of the triangles (see figure below). This polygon is **not** the convex hull, because it does not include the space between each peak. I guess it has a name in maths but I can't remember what is it.

[image]

Comment: The title refers to the "right notation", but from the question it appears that you're actually interested in the *right terminology*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The piecewise linear curve is called the *upper envelope*.  Algebraically, it is the maximum of the linear functions. The whole polygon is the *boundary* of the union of the triangles.